# webzop/yii2-notifications: push notifications not showing up (at all)

Tags: php, push-notification, notifications, yii2

So yeah, I am using Yii2 to create notifications (webzop/yii2-notifications: latest version), based on events in the application. I need to create a push notification when something happens (eg: New follower [followerName]).

My problem is that I don't get any errors. The push notification is just not showing up :(

I did setup everything correctly. There is no need to worry about the configuration in `web.php`.
I did create a notification. It works perfectly: I get the notification on the `screen` and `mail` channels.
Yep, the notifications are stored just fine in the database.

Any ideas? I don't even know what to do anymore.